# How does one prove that constructive type theory is isomorphism-invariant?

Tags: type-theory, meta-math, homotopy-type-theory

In his paper *Structuralism, Invariance and Univalence* ([pdf](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/preprints/siu.pdf)), Steve Awodey makes the following claim about constructive type theory:

> The system of type theory has the important property that any definable property of objects is invariant.
> Thus if $P(X)$ is any type that is definable in the system over a basic type $X$, then the following inference is derivable:
> $$ A \cong B, P(A) \vdash P(B) $$
> The proof is a straightforward induction on the construction of $P(X)$.

**My question** is: can anyone give me a precise formulation of this theorem and perhaps point me to a proof? The first stumbling block for me is that I don't know how $A \cong B$ is formalised in type theory.

As for the system of type theory he is referring to, he writes:

> The basic operations of what is called *constructive type theory*, starting with a basic object or "type of individuals" $X$, are as follows:
> $$ 0, 1, A+B, A \times B, A \rightarrow B, \sum_{(x : A)} B(x), \prod_{(x : A)} B(x), Id_{A}(x, y) $$

Comment: Loosely speaking, for A, B:U, if A and B are isomorphic, then A=_U B by univalence. From A=_U B it follows that if some type P(A) is inhabited, then so is P(B) (by transport.)